# Get number of days between two Dates excluding weekends

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, date

I subtract two dates using below code

```
Dim OpenDate, ClosedDate As DateTime
dim Result as String
OpenDate = Convert.ToDateTime(some string contain date and time)
ClosedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(some string contain date and time)
Result = ClosedDate.Subtract(OpenDate).ToString
```

it works fine with correct result in format (day.hour:minute:second )

what i need is

if period between closed and opened date contain Friday or Saturday subtract from result

Ex. if result 9.03:02:10  contain 2 Saturday and Friday it must be 6.03:02:10  and so on

Comment: What are the normal operating hours?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A naive but readable approach:

```
Public Shared Function GetBusinessDays(startDay As DateTime, endDay As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim today = Date.Today
    Dim weekend = {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}
    Dim businessDays = 
        From d In Enumerable.Range(0, (endDay.Date - startDay.Date).Days + 1)
        Select day = today.AddDays(d)
        Where Not weekend.Contains(day.DayOfWeek)
    Return businessDays.Count()
End Function
```

Test:

```
Dim days As Int32 = GetBusinessDays(Date.Now, Date.Now.AddDays(9))
Console.Write(days) ' 7
```

The LINQ query first creates a range of integers from 0 to days (+1 because including last day). Then it creates `Date` objects via `today.AddDays(days)`. Since `weekend` is an array of `DayOfWeek` you can use `Enumerable.Contains` to take only dates which are not weekend-dates. The last step is to execute the query by using `Enumerable.Count` to get the number of business days.

You could improve it by providing a [`ParamArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ct363x9h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the banking-holidays:

```
Public Shared Function GetBusinessDays(startDay As DateTime, endDay As DateTime, ParamArray bankHoliday As Date()) As Integer
    Dim today = Date.Today
    Dim nonWorkingDays = New HashSet(Of Date)(bankHoliday)
    Dim weekend = {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}
    Dim businessDays =
        From d In Enumerable.Range(0, (endDay - startDay).Days + 1)
        Select day = today.AddDays(d)
        Where Not weekend.Contains(day.DayOfWeek) AndAlso Not nonWorkingDays.Contains(day)
    Return businessDays.Count()
End Function
```

That works as it is even if you don't have bank holiday days. If you have one or multiple you can either pass a real array as argument or single objects like here for christmas:

```
Dim christmas = New Date(2014, 12, 25)
Dim days As Int32 = GetBusinessDays(Date.Now, Date.Now.AddDays(9), christmas)
```

or few single objects:

```
Dim christmasEve = New Date(2014, 12, 24)
Dim days As Int32 = GetBusinessDays(Date.Now, Date.Now.AddDays(9), christmasEve, christmas)
```

Answer (score 2):

It should really be:

```
Select day = startDay.AddDays(d)
```

As the startday of the range specified may not always be today.

Comment: For everybody who is confused by this answer, this should be more like a comment on the answer by @tim-schmelter