# Calculate 2 dates excluding weekends VB net

Tags: vb.net, date, vb.net-2010, weekend

I'm trying compute the dates of Due date into Date Returned. And if the date return pass the due date in one day. there will be a fine.

This is my code in computation

```
Dim st As Integer = MetroDateTime1.Value.Date.Subtract(Label9.Text).Days

If (Label6.Text) > (MetroDateTime1.Value.Date) Then _
  MessageBox.Show("Date return must not below to date borrowed", _
  "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

  MetroDateTime1.Focus()

ElseIf (st > 0) Then
  MetroTextBox7.Text = (st * 5).ToString()
Else
  MetroTextBox7.Text = 0
End If
```

'Metrotextbox7 is the textbox for fines. But, how to compute the dates excluding the weekends?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837943/get-number-of-days-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends

Answer (score 1):

'get business Days

```
   Public Shared Function GetBusinessDays(startDay As DateTime, endDay As DateTime) As Integer

    Dim today = Date.Today
    Dim weekend = {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}
    Dim businessDays = 
    From d In Enumerable.Range(0, (endDay.Date - startDay.Date).Days + 1)
    Select day = today.AddDays(d)
    Where Not weekend.Contains(day.DayOfWeek)

    Return businessDays.Count()

 End Function
```

[already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837943/get-number-of-days-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends)